# gps marker on google maps android

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am developing an application which shows the current location of the user. I want to display a marker on the current location of the user.

I have used an image as marker to display current location. But i want to display an animated arrow showing the range just like in the google maps android app. Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this. Any sample code will be of great help...

Answer (score -2):

try this tricky solution...
if u use javascript, try setInterval() to cahnge image if .gif doesn't work.

function runAnimation(callback){
 setInterval(function(){
  // set new marker here
  // var newVal = callback(); <-- use callback to get new value
 }
 , 500); // interval in millisec
}

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am not using javascript. I want to set the marker in the Android app...